# Некорректно работает margin-top

Tags: html, css

Друзья, всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня margin-top работает на всю страницу вообще, а не на логотип, как я указал?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Викинги</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="header__menu">
                    <li class="header__menu-item">
                        <a href="#" class="header__menu-item-link header__menu-item-link-active">1 cезон</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__menu-item">
                        <a href="#" class="header__menu-item-link">2 cезон</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__menu-item">
                        <a href="#" class="header__menu-item-link">3 cезон</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__menu-item">
                        <a href="#" class="header__menu-item-link">4 cезон</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__menu-item">
                        <a href="#" class="header__menu-item-link">5 cезон</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__menu-item">
                        <a href="#" class="header__menu-item-link">6 cезон</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>

        <main class="main">
            <section class="hero">
                <div class="container">
                    <img class="hero__logo" src="img/hero__logo.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>

        <footer class="footer"></footer>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.header__menu {
    display: flex;
    gap: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header__menu-item-link {
    font-size: 36px;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

.header__menu-item-link-active {
    color: #85CCDC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #85CCDC;
}

.header__menu-item-link:hover {
    color: #85CCDC;
}

.main {
    background-image: url('../img/hero.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.hero__logo {
    display: block;
    max-width: 880px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 328px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://doka.guide/html/flow/#shlopyvanie-i-vypadenie-otstupov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменял margin на padding, все отработало корректно

Comment: можно было и в виде комментария под своим вопросом то оставить, а не выдавать за полноценный ответ

Comment: Да можно и как ответ оставить, так хотя бы понятно сразу, что вопрос закрыт.